# setBackgroundImage for UIButton in IOS 7.1 not working

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to change the button background image. This code is working fine with IOS 6/7. After I upgrade to IOS 7.1 suddenly it is stop working.

```
[monday setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toggleTopRight"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

BWT: the image is ok, because this code is being called in view will appear and this ok there ... when i press on the button that need to change the setBackgroundImage it's not working.

Comment: need a little more info. Are you sure *nothing* else has changed? Did you move to asset catalog for the images? Can you break point here and quick look the image returned from the call to UIImage?

Comment: have you tried with image file name extension like toggleTopRight.png?

Comment: i am sure the asset is ok. the thing is that i call this method in the View will appear ( the same code ) the button change the background image but when i called this method from the button event it's not working.

Comment: check if the control state is correct. isn't the button disabled?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug on 7.1 SDK and Xcode 5.1.

The workaround is to call [UIButton setNeedsLayout] after your changes.

That should do the trick.

Comment: This being haunting out project since 7.1 was released. What I also do to make sure that BG changes are taken is that I change the BG image for UIControlStateNormal as well as UIControlStateDisabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I finally found out that setting a button's (background) image doesn't work on iOS 7.1, if the button is disabled.

Not sure if this fixes your problem, but it was mine. Calling `setNeedsLayout` didn't help in my case, unfortunately. What you can do as a workaround is either to override UIButton or to add a category that contains a method like the following to set an image:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)img forButtonState:(UIControlState)state
    BOOL shouldEnable = self.enabled;
    self.enabled = YES;
    [self setBackgroundImage:img forState:state];
    self.enabled = shouldEnable;
}
```

Filed a bug report for this issue (16497031).

Answer (score 1):

For me it's the foreground image that covered the background image. So make your foreground image transparent then the background image will show. Setting background image actually works fine now.